# If two objects are declared in a single line, in which order are they constructed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, object-construction

Let's say a class has been defined as

```
class A {
//.....
};
```

and now I am creating two objects as

```
A a,b;
```

In what order are `a` and `b` created? Is it defined by the standard?

Comment: The comma in a declaration is not the comma operator, it's merely a separator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Comma Operator work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Comment: In this case it is not the comma operator.

Comment: @Zakkery No.  We are not using the comma operator here

Comment: You could test this.

Comment: @NathanOliver that question contains all answers. Look at comment 4 by CygnusX1. It explains when comma is operator and when it is not, and how it behaves.

Comment: @Zakkery But it does not answer in which order are the objects initialized.

Comment: @donjuedo ..I can test it but I wouldn't know if the result is implementation dependent or not

Comment: @pasha, You are right.  There could be a difference between the implementation and the standard.  Then again, getting an answer on StackOverflow could leave you wondering if there is a difference between the answer and the standard.  ;-)

Comment: @donjuedo Not if the answer quotes the standard. ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver  Excellent!

Comment: IMO if you actually depend on a particular order of construction in any way, you should make that clear by setting the declarations apart (regardless of what order the Standard guarantees for a single-line declaration).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From 8 Declarators  [dcl.decl] 3:

> Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

It goes on to say

> A declaration with several declarators is usually equivalent to the corresponding sequence of declarations each with a single
>   declarator. That is
>   `T D1, D2, ... Dn;`
>   is usually equivalent to
>   `T D1; T D2; ... T Dn;`
>   where `T` is a decl-specifier-seq and each `Di` is an init-declarator. An exception occurs when a name introduced by one of
>   the declarators hides a type name used by the decl-specifiers, so that when the same decl-specifiers are used in a subsequent
>   declaration, they do not have the same meaning.

You can say that they are constructed from left to right.

Comment: Beat me by 45 seconds :-)

Comment: @erip..thanks for the answer. 
Can I do T D1,D2=D1; or not?

Comment: @pasha `T D1,D2=D1;` becomes `T D1; T D2=D1;` by the rules so yes.

Comment: Well, it says 'usually'.

Comment: Yep. It will call default ctor on `D1` and copy assignment on `D2` with `D1`.

Comment: @erip It would call the copy *constructor* for `D2`. Not the copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Brian Indeed. Careless comment on my behalf. :)

Comment: Could someone formulate an example for what the exception to "usually" means?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Main example is when a variable has the same name as the type. `S S,T;` works; `S S; S T;` is an error. Newer example is `auto x=1; auto y=2.0;` works; `auto x=1,y=2.0;` is an error. Those are the only examples the footnote provides. So "usually" is, if anything, a bit of an understatement.

Comment: @Nemo Indeed. And frankly I don't even like the idea of `S S, T;`

Comment: @erip: Yes, no sane person would let something like that through code review, never mind writing it themselves.

Answer (score 52):

C++ spec chapter 8 [dcl.decl], says:

> Each *init-declarator* in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it
>   was in a declaration by itself. (100)

Footnote (100) goes on to say:

> (100) A declaration with several declarators is usually equivalent to the
>   corresponding sequence of declarations each with a single declarator.
>   That is
>
> ```
> T D1, D2, ... Dn;
> ```
>
> is usually equivalent to
>
> ```
>  T D1; T D2; ... T Dn;
> ```

...and then names some exceptions, none of which apply in such simple cases.

So the answer to your question is that the objects are constructed in the order you list them. And no, it is not a comma operator.

Comment: How do you understand 'usually' in this context?

Comment: @SergeyA By reading the exceptions in which case 'usually' becomes 'no' then taking the complement for the affirmative. :)

Comment: @erip, quite a process :)

Comment: @SergeyA As I'm sure you know, that's the name of the game when writing C++. ;D

Answer (score 11):

The order is the written order, from left to right. Also, it's not the comma operator, but simply a list of declarators. When a user-defined comma operator is used, order is in fact unspecified.

See [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) and [declarators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Declarators).

Answer (score 8):

**a** will be created first and then **b**.

Commas in this case **will be used as separators** and not as operators.

For example from wikipedia :

```
    /**
      *  Commas act as separators in this line, not as an operator.
      *  Results: a=1, b=2, c=3, i=0
      */
     int a=1, b=2, c=3, i=0;
```

Answer (score 6):

Standards:

> Declarators [dcl.decl]:
>   Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

Example:

```
class A {
public:
    A(std::string const &s): name(s) 
    { 
        std::cout << "I am " << name << '\n'; 
    }
    std::string name;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    A a("a"), b("b");
}
```

Output:

```
I am a
I am b
```

Comment: This code isn't really a proof that this is true. The standard quote is.